# VirtualHost in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, apache-httpd

I am new in Linux mint. Previously I used LAMP stack in Windows. In Linux Mint I am using VirtualHost means I have to create a file named sitename.conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available location for each Website or Web Application. But I didn't use anything like these in Windows.

Is it mandatory to use VirtualHost in Linux Mint ? or I am doing anything wrong ? Why I have to use VirtualHost ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a million different ways to configure Apache and what you have stated sounds like a possible solution for multiple sites, but not what I would personally use.

I'm a little confused as to why you might use Linux Mint, a desktop Linux distribution for a web server, but I assume you know what you are doing. Maybe you want a test environment for development work.

The [`<VirtualHost>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost) directive is used for hosting for multiple sites on the same server and that is about it. The contents of each `<VirtualHost>` grouping contains the configuration options that are different from the main host and main config.

But then you ask: "Is it mandatory to use `VirtualHost` in Linux Mint?" and the short answer is no, unless you want to host more than one site.

I think the real question is something more like:

> I am trying to set up a development environment with Apache on a Linux
>   Mint desktop and I'm a little unsure how to configure it correctly.
>
> This is what I have currently and it is not working... *list of
>   what you tried and what went wrong*

At the moment, your question is not very clear. Maybe edit your question to include a little more detail on what you are wanting to do with Apache.

Comment: Thanks @Tigger for your reply. I got my answer `But then you ask: "Is it mandatory to use VirtualHost in Linux Mint?" and the short answer is no, unless you want to host more than one site.` Previously I used Windows as Desktop. I didn't do anything like these in Windows, but I used LAMP there.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to setup `<VirtualHost>` configuration if you want to run more than one site on Apache. It is the only way Apache can identify which site `DocumentRoot` directory to serve for each request.

You get two different options which you can read more about on Apache's website: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/